# Update Graph in R Shiny react

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity, shinyapps

I would like to understand why the graph does not update in the RShiny App generated from the code below.

What I try to do:

- Generate a sample of n_data observations from a beta-distribution with certain shape parameters.
- Plot the histogram of this sample, together with its mean.
- Do this e_samples times and keep the means, show an updated graph every second
- Plot the histogram of the vector with e_samples means

```
    library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

# Design the interface
ui <-  fluidPage(titlePanel("Population vs sample"),

                 sidebarLayout(
                   # Function to determine the layout
                   sidebarPanel(
                     sliderInput(
                       'shape1',
                       label = 'Population shape 1:',
                       min = 1,
                       max = 9,
                       value = 2 ,
                       step = 1
                     ),
                     sliderInput(
                       'shape2',
                       label = 'Population shape 2:',
                       min = 1,
                       max = 9,
                       value = 2 ,
                       step = 1
                     ),

                     textInput("n_data", label = "Sample size:",
                               value = '25'),

                     textInput("e_samples", label = "number of samples:",
                               value = '5'),

                     actionButton("RerunButton", "New sample", icon("play"))
                   ),

                   mainPanel(plotOutput('Sample'))
                 ))

# Set up the server
server <- function(input, output) {
  set.seed(1234)
  xvals <- seq(.001, .999, by = 0.001)

  # Define reactive values
  avgs <- reactiveVal(vector(mode = "list", length = 1))
  vals <- reactiveVal(0)
  s <- reactiveVal()
  sample_plot <- reactiveVal()

# This is where I hope to generate a new graph every second.
  observe({
    invalidateLater(1000)
    cat(paste('vals', vals(), '\n'))
    cat(paste('avgs', avgs(), '\n'))
    if (vals() < input$e_samples) {
      s(data.frame(
        d = rbeta(
          n = input$n_data,
          shape1 = as.numeric(input$shape1),
          shape2 = as.numeric(input$shape2)
        )
      ))
      temp <- s()
      vals(vals() + 1)
      averages <- avgs()
      averages[vals()] <- mean(temp$d)
      avgs(averages)
      sample_plot(
        ggplot() +
          geom_histogram(
            data = temp,
            aes(x = d),
            binwidth = 0.1,
            fill = 'white',
            col = 'black'
          ) +
          geom_vline(xintercept = mean(temp$d)) +
          xlim(0, 1) +
          xlab('observation value') +
          ylab('count')
      )
    }
  })



  output$Sample <- renderPlot({
    sample_plot()
  })

  observeEvent(input$RerunButton, {
    vals(0)
  })
  observeEvent(input$RerunButton, {
    avgs(vector(mode = "list", length = 1))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

The code above only updates the graph once. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of your `reactiveValues` that keep changing are triggering your `observe` repeatedly right away. This happens five times in succession, well before 1000 msec has elapsed. To prevent this from happening, you would need to use `isolate` for your `reactiveValues`. See if this gives the right behavior:

```
# Set up the server
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  set.seed(1234)
  xvals <- seq(.001, .999, by = 0.001)

  # Define reactive values
  avgs <- reactiveVal(vector(mode = "list", length = 1))
  vals <- reactiveVal(0)
  s <- reactiveVal()
  sample_plot <- reactiveVal()

  # This is where I hope to generate a new graph every second.
  observe({
    invalidateLater(1000, session)

    #cat(paste('vals', vals(), '\n'))
    #cat(paste('avgs', avgs(), '\n'))

    if (isolate(vals()) < input$e_samples) {
      s(data.frame(
        d = rbeta(
          n = input$n_data,
          shape1 = as.numeric(input$shape1),
          shape2 = as.numeric(input$shape2)
        )
      ))
      temp <- s()
      isolate(vals(vals() + 1))
      averages <- isolate(avgs())
      averages[vals()] <- mean(temp$d)
      avgs(averages)
    }
  })

  sample_plot <- reactive({
    ggplot() +
      geom_histogram(
        data = s(),
        aes(x = d),
        binwidth = 0.1,
        fill = 'white',
        col = 'black'
      ) +
      geom_vline(xintercept = mean(s()$d)) +
      xlim(0, 1) +
      xlab('observation value') +
      ylab('count')
  })

  output$Sample <- renderPlot({
    sample_plot()
  })

  observeEvent(input$RerunButton, {
    vals(0)
  })

  observeEvent(input$RerunButton, {
    avgs(vector(mode = "list", length = 1))
  })
}
```